# How do I limit the creation of new users to specified administrators on ActiveAdmin (Prevent users from creating more users)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

We'd like all users to be able to access ActiveAdmin, however, we would like to limit the creation of new users to specified administrators. The ideal outcome would be that only administrators see the users resource.

Currently, any user can go on to users.rb and create a new user. How do I limit this so that only specified administrators can create users? How do I stop users from seeing this resource unless they are specified as an administrator?

Do I need to add an admin attribute to the users model? From there what do I do?

Using Rails 4 with Devise.

I only have a users.rb model, no adminusers model.

When installing ActiveAdmin I used:

rails g active_admin:install User         # creates / edits the class for use with Devise

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some ability managment:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md#using-the-cancan-adapter

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same @nistvan .. do you know if CanCanCan works with ActiveAdmin ? I know CanCan does but it does not support rails 4

Comment: Yes, I'm using cancancan with rails 4.1.5 and ActiveAdmin and it works.

Comment: Is the setup any different to CanCan?

Comment: Hey @nistvan do i set CanCanCanAdapter instead of CanCanAdapter at: config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter

Comment: ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter should work. You can set up the gem based on the cancancan documentation.

Comment: Got this working, much easier than Pundit to setup! Thanks for your help